# Objetos vazio em RealmDB com Reactotron

Tags: javascript, react-native, realmdb

Estou tendo problemas com os objetos do RealmDB, toda consulta que faço ele retorna porém no Reactotron eles vem vazios independente do que eu faça com o objeto inteiro, ele só aparece se eu desmembrar atributo por atributo para um outro objeto.
Alguém já teve esse problema e resolveu de alguma forma ?
Obs: Ja linkei o realm e o reactotron no projeto.
Segue imagem do reactotron e do código:

Reactotron: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhN1D.png
Código: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsNwk.png

Código em texto:

```
async getAllMov(){
    try{
        const realm = await getRealm();
        const listaMov = realm.objects(MovSchema.schema.name);

        console.tron.log(listaMov[4]);

        const d = {...listaMov[4]};

        console.tron.log(d);

        let dados = {
            movID: listaMov[4].movID,
            titulo: listaMov[4].titulo,
            descricao: listaMov[4].descricao,
            valor: listaMov[4].valor,
            tipo: listaMov[4].tipo
        }; 

        console.tron.log(dados);


    }catch(e){
        console.tron.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Os objetos criados pelo realm não são iguais aos objetos "tradicionais" do js, o fato de não aparecer no console pode ser algo na implementação do `toString`. Provavelmente se você fizer uma conversão simples com JSON.stringfy(d). Outra coisa, usar o "..." em alguns casos não funciona porque isso não chama os getters/setters dos objetos do realm.